# Looping JSON result and setting div html accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a HTML page with a simple structure like this:

```
<li class="slide">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>This is a test.</p>
</li>
<li class="slide">
    <h1>Hello Again</h1>
    <p>This is another test.</p>
</li>
<li class="slide">
    <h1>Hello For The Last Time</h1>
    <p>This is yet another test.</p>
</li>
```

Now I have `.json` file with some values in it... This is as follows

```
var slides = [
{"maand": "September", "titel": "First Title", "inhoud": "Content 1"},
{"maand": "Oktober", "titel": "Second Title", "inhoud": "Content 2"},
{"maand": "November", "titel": "Third Title", "inhoud": "Content 3"},
]
```

**Now I'm trying to make sure that every .slide h1 get's the title from the json file**
And for some reason it's always assigning the last title ('Third Title').

##I tried the following loop##

```
$.each(slides, function(i, data){
    $('li.slide h1').html(data.titel)           
});
```

But this is always returning the last item from the `.json` file.
I also tried this, With the same result

```
$.each(slides, function(i,data){

    $('li.slide h1').each(function(){
        $(this).html(data.titel);
    });

});
```

##Solution 1##

I just had to add 1 to the .eq.. Maybe it starts at 1 instead of 0?

```
$.each(slides, function(i,data){
    $('li.slide h1').eq(i+1).html(data.titel);
});
```

Comment: Does you JSON file contain "var slides = "?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var dom=$('li.slide h1');  
$.each(slides, function(i, data){
    dom.eq(i).html(data.titel)           
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CwCMP/1/)**

Comment: i didnt know about eq(i) -- awesome

Comment: I suggest you to move `$('li.slide h1')` to variable outside of `each` cycle, currently you make DOM query on each iteratiion.

Comment: Updated question with solution.. Just had to add +1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer this

```
$.each(slides, function(i, data){
    $('li:eq('+i+').slide h1').html(data.titel)           
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H7J3X/

Comment: Thanks! both. Didn't know about the eq function. is this the best practice.. Like i'm doing it to populate the content.. Or should i append them with Jquery?